# How to Handle List inside Connection in Graphql Relay

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, relayjs

I have a schema like this:

```
type SectionItem = {
  a: String
}

type SectionRowConnection {
  pageInfo: PageInfo!
  edges: [SectionRowEdge]
}

type SectionRowEdge {
  node: [SectionItem]
  cursor: String!
}
```

I want to get a list in each node of connection, and when I run below query manually, everything works fine:

```
query {
  sectionRows(type:someType){
    edges{
      node{
        a
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm using Relay in client, but I get this error trying to build the query using relay:

> ERROR:
>   Encountered 1 error(s):
>   - @connection used on invalid field `sectionRows`. Expected the field type `SectionRowConnection` to have an `edges { node }` field that returns an object, interface, or union.

As the Error suggests, I can not use List inside a relay connection, but I want to have a schema like this, any Ideas on how to use relay with this schema or recommend a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to wrap the result list inside an object, i.e. each node is of `SectionRow` type which is a `graphQlObjectType` that has an `items` field, the list is inside the items list. here is the resulting schema:

```
type SectionItem = {
  a: String
}

type SectionRow = {
  items: [SectionItem]
}

type SectionRowConnection {
  pageInfo: PageInfo!
  edges: [SectionRowEdge]
}

type SectionRowEdge {
  node: SectionRow
  cursor: String!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Relay [spec](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm#sec-Node):

> An “Edge Type” must contain a field called node. This field must return either a Scalar, Enum, Object, Interface, Union, or a Non‐Null wrapper around one of those types. Notably, this field *cannot* return a list.

In other words, `SectionRowConnection` does not meet Relay's requirements for a connection type because its node field is a List. There is no workaround for this other than modifying your schema so that `node`'s type is `SectionItem!` instead of `[SectionItem]`. If you want to use Relay, your schema must be compliant with the Relay specification.

The connection itself represents a collection of individual nodes (or "resources" if we borrow REST terminology), with each edge connecting the root node to an individual node in the collection.

For example, we can imagine a single User node that has a `friends` field that returns a UserConnection. Each edge in the connection would represent the association between the original User node and one of the friend users. Each edge would have a single User node.

This collection of User nodes can naturally be sorted and filtered as needed. However, if we wanted to *group* them together according to some criteria (similar to `GROUP BY` in SQL), we would create a separate UserGroup type and a UserGroupConnection. Each UserGroup node inside a UserGroupConnection would then itself have some field that is a UserConnection. Even in this scenario, *each connection's edge still only has one node*.

It's unclear from just your schema if you were trying to do just simple filtering or "grouping" your nodes as shown above. Either way, conceptually, there is no reason to ever have an edge return a List for its `node` field.

Comment: Well This is the scenario: The application is something that looks like a store, home page may contain a lot of rows(the connection here) and each row has a list of items, something like appstore's apps section, so in this case, the simplest idea is to have a connection of lists, but relay does not allow it.